# SELF- TEST FAILED. Gnome disks

Tags: hard-disk

I tried to scan the disk health but got this error.
Image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/oU7TxEnBjmuEcahh6
Help, please.
Video: https://youtu.be/FEmR0C8Fhx8
I have back up to Google Drive so I am not worried at all.
Thanks, Jonathan.
The read error rate went from 1 to 2 fast.
Does it need replacing?

Comment: I would rely on the result of the self-test. When it reports FAILED something is wrong, and I would replace the drive.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the reply. I will soon replace this drive with a healthy one.

Comment: Just wondering uncorrectable sector count means it failed to relocate itself? Also, how does a bad sector get relocated?

Comment: So would I need to do a format if it shows an uncorrectable sector count?

Comment: There are some spare memory cells, that can replace cells, that are getting flaky. When the drive has activated all spare cells, things can get bad pretty fast. Sometimes, the situation is stable (with a constant number of bad sectors), and the drive can continue to work for a long time, but we don't know, and it is better to replace the drive before it creates severe problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will replace the drive soon. Hopefully, the new drive is in good health as I had it sitting on a shelf for a long time and also the warranty ended and I have not scanned for any bad sectors on the new drive.

Comment: Good luck with the now old drive :-)

Comment: @sudodus Thanks. :)

Comment: The only problem is that I don't know how to replace a drive.

Comment: What computer is it and what drive (please specify brand name and model of computer and drive(s))? **Please avoid using the failing drive (except later on in order to save what can still be saved)**.

Comment: If you have valuable data on the drive, data that are not yet backed up, you may consider creating a cloned copy of the drive with `ddrescue` and use recovering tools on the cloned copy. See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) and scroll down to 'Advanced repair...'. It might be best to create a fresh Linux operating system, install the extra tools that you want, and restore your personal data from the backup. Unless you have a very special system, a fresh installation is probably the most efficient way to get what you need.

Comment: Drives:    Local Storage: total: 232.89 GiB used: 102.19 GiB (43.9%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD2500AAKX-00ERMA0 size: 232.89 GiB 
           speed: <unknown> serial: <filter> 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 22.79 GiB used: 17.32 GiB (76.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: /boot size: 471.7 MiB used: 108.7 MiB (23.0%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-3: /home size: 201.08 GiB used: 84.76 GiB (42.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4 
           ID-4: swap-1 size: 3.82 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3

Comment: Type: Desktop System: Dell product: OptiPlex 380 v: N/A serial: <filter> Chassis:  type: 15 serial: <filter>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130502/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jon).

Comment: Cant right now as I am in college and the lesson will start soon. I'll send a chat when available.